# Service mix update a webpage

Tags: apache-servicemix

I have the following problem:

I have a queue with messages, and my goal is when a new message arrives, it should be transformed and update a webpage automatically.

I have already implemented in ServiceMix a consumer for that queue that reads and transform, but I don’t know how I can push that information to the webpage.

Anybody knows how can do that?

Comment: You could make your webpage a  camel-velocity  template (webpage.vm) with 
 dynamic entity as variable . which gets replaced by your transformed data. In camel  you can then  send it to your template as `<to id="_lookup" uri="velocity:templates/html/dynamic-webpage.vm"/>`  Hope this helps

Comment: I think you should post some code (camel route?) for the people here to better help you. As it is explained now it is difficult to give you any advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did this by using a socket.IO and rest service in NodeJS. The camel sends a message (REST message) to this service with the data and the socket.IO will update the page information:

Camel Receives->(Send to NodeJS by using a REST service)->Node JS will update page using socket.io